# Gradient Underlined Text

Tags: css

I'm using the CSS below, to apply the underline in the attached image.

I was hoping someone could help me bring this home with some code to apply the dashed version.

```
 .gradient-underline {
     padding-bottom: 4px;
     position: relative;
}
.gradient-underline::after {
     background: linear-gradient(300deg, rgba(104, 85, 211, 0.9) 0%, rgba(168, 85, 246, 0.9) 100%); 
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     height: 1px;
     width: 100%;
}
```

[image: Before and after image]

Thank you,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider mask in this case:

```css
.gradient-underline {
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  position: relative;
  display:table;
  margin:auto;
  font-size:35px;
}

.gradient-underline::after {
  background: linear-gradient(300deg, rgba(104, 85, 211, 0.9) 0%, red 100%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  /* we show from 0 to 7px then a gap until 9px (2px gap)*/
  -webkit-mask:repeating-linear-gradient(to right,#fff 0 7px,transparent 0 9px);
          mask:repeating-linear-gradient(to right,#fff 0 7px,transparent 0 9px);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="gradient-underline"> a long title here</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not the best solution, but a simple way to get something close to what you want (as long as you know what color background the line is against) could be to use a ::before element with the ::after element. We could use z-index to put it on top of the other and and give it a dashed border of the same color as the background:

```
body{background-color: white;}
.gradient-underline {
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    position: relative;
}
.gradient-underline::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed white;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.gradient-underline::after {
    background: linear-gradient(300deg, rgba(104, 85, 211, 0.9) 0%, rgba(168, 85, 246, 0.9) 100%);
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time to answer.